# INVALID_PAYMENT_INSTRUMENT after requesting model access in Amazon Bedrock

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-bedrock

I was trying to use the GA Amazon Bedrock, but I received the following error when I tried to request models access:

[image: aws bedrock errors]

The error message is the same for every model and I've tried to use different regions.

This account has been active a few years and we're currently using many other services without any troubles. They payment methods are properly set in our organization and, again, there have been no issues so far on other services.

Did I miss any configuration somewhere?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey d3vcho, what region are you in? US East or US West?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I tried to request access on both regions

Comment: Nothing relevant over there. For each model there's an API GET call to Bedrock that returns the error message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally figured out what was going on. After trying to subscribe to one of the foundational models in SageMaker and getting the same error message, I decided to navigate to my Billing details.

I had a bank account based in Europe as default payment method. I then set a VISA card as the default method and tried to request access to the models again, this time successfully.

After that, I switched back to the bank account without any troubles. For some reason, the check for a valid payment instrument doesn't recognize an european bank account.